# Why do library book detectors make my headphones buzz?

Tags: sound, interference, how-does-it-work

Whenever I enter or exit a library while wearing headphones (cheaper intra-aural type), I hear loud buzzing as I pass through the book detector gate. I can vaguely speculate at a high level that there's some sort of field that detects something on the books, and that field also interferes with headphones, but that answer is unsatisfying.

- **How do library book detectors work?** All the sources I find are uncredible and slightly conflicting, but it appears that the tag on the book has some sort of circuit that is wirelessly charged or discharged when a book is checked in/out. Somehow a field detects when a capacitor is charged.
- **What is it about headphones that makes the buzzing?** Does whatever field interfere with whatever mechanism by which the headphones make noise?

Somewhat simpler explanations are preferred (I've taken intros to circuits, electronics, and signals, but not much beyond that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **How do library book detectors work?**

Two of the common library book detection systems are magnetic strip based (e.g. [3M Tattle-Tape](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/library-systems-NA/library-technologies/library-system-products/em-security/security-strips/)), and RFID library management systems (see [this publication](http://www.academia.edu/170162/RFID_Technology_A_Revolution_in_Library_Management)).

The magnetic systems work by embedding a double-layered strip of material into the book cover or spine, where one strip is a permanent magnet polarized one way, while the other strip is a magnetizable strip that gets polarized one way or the other by the sensitizing / desensitizing device at the check-out desk.

If both strips are polarized in the same direction, the resultant strip has a high magnetic field, while polarizing them in opposite directions causes the fields to pretty much cancel out.

Detection masts at the library exits (again taking the [3M example](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/mediawebserver?mwsId=66666UgxGCuNyXTtN8TENXT2EVtQEcuZgVs6EVs6E666666--&fn=Security%20Solutions%20Brochure.pdf)) detect this magnetization as a "wobble" in the magnetic field when a book that has not been checked out passes through - a desensitized strip does not cause a detectable wobble.

RFID library management systems cost more per strip, but provide the added benefit of specific book identification. These do work the way the question suggests: An RFID tag with an embedded radio frequency antenna and transponding circuitry with an unique ID is embedded within each book, again possibly concealed in the spine or in a cover pocket.

The RFID "tag" is energized by RF energy emitted by the sensing masts. The tag's RF coil picks up this energy, which is then rectified and used to power the circuitry within the tag. The transponder then responds with the ID of the tag, and hence of the book.

In neither system is there any field detecting the charging of a capacitor, as posited in the question.

---

> **What is it about headphones that makes the buzzing?**

The detection masts at the exits emit some electromagnetic signal. Especially in the case of the magnetic strip systems, this signal is of fairly low frequency, which can cause corresponding ripples in the amplification circuitry of the headphones. A small ripple in the input stage of amplification evidently will convert to a strong buzz after amplification. This can be partially or completely abated by suitable filtering incorporated into the headphone's amplifier.

Depending on the shielding and filtering incorporated in the headphones, it is worthwhile examining their behavior when passing between shopping mall loss-detection masts. Also, some headphones will even pick up a buzz when moved close to a conventional domestic CCFL lamp, many of which emit electromagnetic signals at 30-50 KHz.